# Access Session/ViewState Multiple Times in a Scope

Tags: c#, asp.net

When using `Session` property, a `set`/`get` would be written either as the following:

```
    public int MySessionPro
    {
        get
        {
            return Session["MySessionKey"] == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(Session["MySessionKey"]);
        }
        set
        {
            Session["MySessionKey"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Or as the following:

```
        public int MySessionPro
        {
            get
            {
                object mySessionPro = Session["MySessionKey"];
                return mySessionPro == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(mySessionPro);
            }
            set
            {
                Session["MySessionKey"] = value;
            }
        }
```

**What is more efficient/better perfomance? The first approach of the second?**

The same exact question applies by replacing every "Session" with "ViewState" in the code above. Again, are the two approaches different in term of efficency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either with a `ViewState` or a `Session` the answer is the same: the difference in performance will be very small, unless you have a lot of variables in your `ViewState` or `Session` object.

In your first approach, you will query for your variable 1 times more than in the second.

In the second, you just have one more variable you set.

Since querying for your variable takes more operations than just setting an extra variable, the second approach should be more efficient/better than the first one.

Comment: I think so too, I was betting on someone telling me that .NET Framework 4/4.5 is enhanced in a way that it detects these kinds of repetitions and automatically avoid re-quering my Session/ViewState my internally store a temp variable (as I did in the second implementation).
But seems like nobody would say that.

Comment: @yazanpro perhaps it does that, I never heard of it but it's possible. But even if the compiler checks for that kind of repetitions, I think it's better to be sure about that, and write it explicitly, but that's just an opinion.